# What's the default Php's response to a kill signal?

Tags: php, shell, daemon

I have a simple php script like this:

```
<?php    

function doSomething() {      
    $f = fopen("something.txt","a+");
    fwrite($f, "Starting at " . date("H:i:s") . "\n");
    fclose($f);
    while(true) {
      // Do some stuff here
    }    
}

register_shutdown_function(function () {
    $f = fopen("something.txt","a+");
    fwrite($f, "\nEnding at " . date("H:i:s") . "\n");
    fclose($f);
});

?>
```

When I daemonize this function with

```
daemon --start -name somename --pidfile=/var/run/somename.pid /usr/bin/run_something
```

then I try to

```
daemon --stop -name somename --pidfile=/var/run/somename.pid
```

It writes "Starting at [time]" but not "Ending at [time]"

What am I doing wrong here?

**Notice the documentation of "daemon --stop" says that it's sending kill not kill -9**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function)

> Note:
>   Shutdown functions will not be executed if the process is killed with a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal. While you cannot intercept a SIGKILL, you can use pcntl_signal() to install a handler for a SIGTERM which uses exit() to end cleanly.

Comment: I'll try that and send write feedback here